# Perform hypothesis testing on coefficients from separate linear models

Tags: r, lsmeans, emmeans

Imagine I have two separate `lm` objects

```
data(mtcars)

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
lm2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = mtcars)
```

In this case I'd like to compare both `wt` coefficients, and perform a hypothesis test on the null that the coefficients in both models are equal(for technical reason I need to actually have two models, rather than just including an interaction)

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. Do you mean something like a likelihood ratio test? E.g. `anova(lm1, lm2, test = "LRT")`?

Comment: No, I want to do a direct test on the coefficient itself, as the package `multcomp` lets you do for coefficients within a single model

Comment: So why not use the full model and then use `multcomp` to sequentially test for the significance of all predictor variables? Isn't that exactly the purpose of `multicomp`?

Comment: PS. Your question is still incomplete: *"and perform a hypothesis test on the null that the coefficients in both models (...) ..."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to perform a hypothesis test on the estimates, I suggest a fully Bayesian model, which will get you the full posterior distribution of every variable.

`rstanarm` is based on `Stan`, and offers convenient functions that mimic the usual `lm`, `glm` syntax; if you want to know more about `Stan`/`RStan`, see [here](http://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan).

Based on the posterior distributions of every variable, we can then perform e.g. a *t* test and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare the full posterior densities for every variable.

Here is what you could do:

1. Perform the model fits.

   ```
   library(rstanarm);
   lm1 <- stan_lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, prior = NULL);
   lm2 <- stan_lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = mtcars, prior = NULL);
   ```

   Note how easy it is to run a fully Bayesian linear model with `rstanarm`.
2. Extract the posterior densities for all shared coefficients (in this case, the `(Intercept)` and `wt`).

   ```
   library(tidyverse);
   shared.coef <- intersect(names(coef(lm1)), names(coef(lm2)));
   shared.coef;
   #[1] "(Intercept)" "wt"
   df1 <- lm1 %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       select(one_of(shared.coef)) %>%
       mutate(model = "lm1");
   df2 <- lm2 %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       select(one_of(shared.coef)) %>%
       mutate(model = "lm2");
   ```

   The posterior densities for 4000 MCMC draws are stored in two `data.frame`s.
3. We plot the posterior densities.

   ```
   # Plot posterior densities for all common parameters
   bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
       gather(var, value, 1:length(shared.coef)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(value, colour = model)) +
           geom_density() +
           facet_wrap(~ var, scale = "free");
   ```

   [image]
4. We compare the posterior density distributions of every shared parameter in a *t* test and a KS test. Here I'm using library `broom` to tidy-up the output.

   ```
   # Perform t test and KS test
   library(broom);
   res <- lapply(1:length(shared.coef), function(i)
       list(t.test(df1[, i], df2[, i]), ks.test(df1[, i], df2[, i])));
   names(res) <- shared.coef;
   lapply(res, function(x) bind_rows(sapply(x, tidy)));
   #$`(Intercept)`
   #   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter  conf.low conf.high
   #1 -4.497093  30.07725  34.57434 -104.8882       0  7155.965 -4.581141 -4.413045
   #2        NA        NA        NA    0.7725       0        NA        NA        NA
   #                              method alternative
   #1            Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
   #2 Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test   two-sided
   #
   #$wt
   #   estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic      p.value parameter  conf.low
   #1 0.1825202 -3.097777 -3.280297  9.120137 1.074479e-19  4876.248 0.1432859
   #2        NA        NA        NA  0.290750 0.000000e+00        NA        NA
   #  conf.high                             method alternative
   #1 0.2217544            Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
   #2        NA Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test   two-sided
   #
   #There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
   ```

   (The warnings originate from unequal factor levels when binding rows, and can be ignored.)